# Payment process in WebView(Android)

Tags: android, payment-gateway

I have a web address for the payment gateway (where I need to enter credit card number, etc.). Can I open this page using WebView and make a payment directly into my application? Without opening separate web client like chrome? Does google has any restrictions or security rule on the publication of application, where the user enter his credit/debit card information directly into WebView?

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.one97.paytm&hl=en see this app, they use webview for payment, it is possible. you just have to find how it can be achieved

Comment: try juspay payment gateway

Comment: check this https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/mobile/ht_mpl-itemPayment-Android/

Answer (score 2):

You can open your payment page in a WebView in Android without any restriction. I'm using this method in few apps, for few years now, and I didn't had any problem so far.

But on iOS, there are some restrictions. You can't sell digital goods from a WebView that can be used in the app.

Comment: and is that OK to sell in app products, or say, an upgrade to a premium account and having the user pay using e webView (i.e. bypassing Google's IAP) ?

Comment: Yes. It's the same thing as, the customer go to your website, and login and buy whatever he wants to buy. But be careful to change the content rating of the app in google play, if you add in app purchase in your app.

Comment: but what about Google play store terms & agreements? Doesn't it says you need to use the in app billing system ?? In my case, I want to charge my app's users (for a premium account which will unlock features).. Do I need to use Google In App Billing system? thanks.

Comment: You can use their payment system, but is not mandatory.. where did you find this information, that you need to use their payment method?